# Should you delete your Saves folder when reverting to vanilla Skyrim if you want to retain those saves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, linux

I have installed a load of mods over the past few weeks and now have a much clearer idea of what I want to keep and what I don't. My /Data folder is a mess as a result.

I was considering doing a clean install but I came across [this guide](https://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:Make_Skyrim_Vanilla_Again), which apparently gives you the same result, but you don't have to re-download several gigabytes of data, you just have to be careful and methodical about what you delete.

The guide says, in step 11, to delete "all files and subdirectories", from `My Documents/My Games/Skyrim` which would include the Saves folder.

**What is the point in deleting the Saves folder if one wants to keep one's saves?** Surely it should be left [and backups made, just in case].

FYI I am on Linux, I don't know if that makes any difference. I don't think it does, apart from the fact that the Saves folder is - for me - in

```
/home/user/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/compatdata/72850/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/My Documents/My Games/Skyrim/
```

rather than

```
 C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Games/Skyrim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted everything in the /Skyrim folder as stated in the question, apart from the /Saves folder. I then reacquired/verified any missing files through Steam. Everything was fine and I was able to use my saves just as before. The game also ran noticeably smoother.